# Merging yearly .gdb geodatabases

Tags: database, merge, time-series, gis

I'm working with a database of land parcels and their corresponding crops per year ([source](https://www.europeandataportal.eu/data/en/dataset/25943e6e-bb27-4b7a-b240-150ffeaa582e))

My end goal is to create a predictive model for crop type, given land parcel. For example, if in the past 4 years a farmer grew soy, soy, corn and corn, what is the likely crop he'll be growing in 5th year.

There are 8 individual .gdb databases for years 2009 to 2016, but the schemas are the same; most importantly, land parcel geometry (polygon) and type of crop.

Ideally I'd want to work with one (time series) database where I have one row per parcel geometry, and one column per year (to record crop type for that year).

What is the best way to achieve this?

A lot of polygons 'repeat' across the years but with very slight variations in borders. So I guess any two polygons that overlap more than a given threshold should be given the same unque id. Samples:

2016 (green) and 2009 (red)
[image]

Only 2009 (red)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I took:

Step 1. Convert gdb files to shape file, this is because apparently gdb is not an open source format and limited in tool support

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" 2009.shp 2009.gdb
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" 2010.shp 2010.gdb

.... same for other years ....
```

File names denote the dataset corresponding to that year.

Step 2. Import shape files into PostGIS

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 28992 2009.shp 2009 | psql -U postgres -d crops

.... same for other years ....
```

28992 is the SRID that I found with the help of this [website](http://prj2epsg.org/search).

Step 3. Add a foreign key column in 2010 table which stores the polygon id from 2009. Let's call it `global_geo_id`. If it's set for a polygon in 2010 it means it's the 'same' polygon from 2009.

Step 4. Do a spacial join between years in PostGIS

```
update "2010"  
set global_geo_id = "2009".global_geo_id 
from "2009" where 
ST_Intersects("2009".geom,"2010".geom) and 
(st_area(st_intersection("2009".geom,"2010".geom))/("2009".shape_area)) > 0.8
```

0.8 is a similarity threshold; the higher you set the more conservative the matching will be.

Step 5. Repeat steps 3, 4 for other years.

Answer (score 1):

As you say .gdb, I assume you'd like to use or stick to ArcGIS?
In any case, a very basic approach to get you going (if getting you going is what you need): join the feature's tables.
If there is any sort of unique ID that is consistent throughout all GDBs, join them on this attribute.
(if not, there should also be a tool for a spatial join with a threshold to get the same result, as you suggested)
You can choose which colums to include in the joned table, and you can export the joined tables to a new GDB.
 Correct me, but I think this might be sufficent for your needs (I just brainstormed here).
If not, there are lots and lots of options using gdal/ogr, python, R, postgis, ... maybe you can list your preferrences in software?

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply i posted my solution below.